# I bridged my wireless and LAN connections on my laptop and connected it with my desktop. Why is my desktop not recieving an internet connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, bridge

I am trying to connect my desktop to my laptop with an Ethernet cable to use the laptop's internet connection. I have followed the instructions of one article to bridge the LAN connection and wireless connection on my laptop and all I would have to do after that is connect the two computers with an Ethernet cable and my desktop would have access to the internet through my laptop. After plugging the Ethernet cable into both machines, my desktop still couldn't access the internet. I kept searching through multiple articles assuming there was something wrong with the first article, but they all told me the same thing, so I assume it's something on my end.

Since everything seems to be in accordance to the instructions on my laptop, I assume it's with my desktop, which is a custom make so that would make it even more likely. Both computers are running Windows 7 64-bit.

[DxDiag Results (Desktop)](http://pastebin.com/ajfakQeg)

[DxDiag Results (Laptop)](http://pastebin.com/5FHm98Yb)

[image]


   [image]


   [image]


   [image]

I did everything correctly according to every bridging article I found on the internet. Why is my desktop receiving an internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have bridged them, Undo the bridge then connect your wifi to the internet and make sure the internet is working ( this is important ) then right click on your wifi card, icon then select the tab that say's sharing then check the box that say's "Allow other network user's to connect through this computer's internet connection's, Some version's of windows 7 have a drop down where you can select your lan card. your internet should now work over your lan card you could hookup another computer or a router if you wish to connect several computers to it